# Getting marginal effects from a logistic regression with interactions using margins

Tags: r, logistic-regression, marginal-effects, modelsummary

I'm running three logistic models with all categorical variables, some of them binary but most of them with 3 or more factors as values, the first would be the base model, the second have 2 interaction terms and the third have a three-way interaction.

```
model1 <- glm(y ~ x + z + a + b + c + d, data=df,
              family=binomial(link="logit"), na.action=na.omit)

model2 <- glm(y ~ x*d + z*d + a*d + b*d + c*d, data=df,
              family=binomial(link="logit"), na.action=na.omit)

model3 <- glm(y ~ x*d + z*d + a*d + b*d + c*d + x*z*d, data=df, 
              family=binomial(link="logit"), na.action=na.omit)
```

So I wanted to calculate the marginal effects of the three models using  `margins`, it just works fine in the first case, but in the second and third model (the ones with interactions) no coefficient is reported for the interactions terms, just for the same variables reported in the first model.

```
library(margins)

mod0 <- margins(model1)
mod1 <- margins(model2)
mod2 <- margins(model3)


library(modelsummary)

modelsummary(list(mod0, mod1, mod3))
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, there is no interactions in the marginal effects output.

I have reviewed the documentation, thought at first I should use the `at` argument and that would solve it, but I had some troubles interpretting the output, not all coefficients match the possitive or negative sign of the base model with interactions and it also lacks p-values and confidence intervals, also thought about `dydx` but wasn't sure how to explicit all the interactions I need and what to do with the three-way interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The `margins` package defines a "marginal effect" as the slope of the outcome model with respect to one of the predictors. In other words, We are taking the derivative of y with respect to x, then with respect to z, then with respect to the other variables. So each variable has a marginal effect, but the *interaction terms* do *not* have marginal effects. I recommend you read the good vignette for `margins`:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html

Alternatively, you may want to look at the vignette for `marginaleffects`, a more recent package which aims to be a "successor" to `margins` (disclaimer: I am the author):

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/marginaleffects.html